# Dynamic arrays in javascript from json

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, flot

i am trying to create javascript flot graphs. i am getting the data from json string, the problem that i am facing is how to parse the data in the correct format to build the arrays

below is the code that i am using:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // initiate layout and plugins
        App.init();

        var xdata = null;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Workshops/GetTestData/@Model.workshop.WorkshopId',
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                xdata = data;
                //alert("Success.");

            }
        });

        // this is the data that i am getting from the ajax call 
        //{"trainees":[{"percentage":0.0,"name":"test user 1","WorkshopScoresId":0,"WorkshopID":12,"TraineeId":5,"PreSocre":0.0,"PostScore":0.0,"Status":1,"Trainee":null,"Workshop":null},{"percentage":0.0,"name":"test user the trainee2222","WorkshopScoresId":0,"WorkshopID":12,"TraineeId":6,"PreSocre":0.0,"PostScore":0.0,"Status":1,"Trainee":null,"Workshop":null}]}

        var arr = xdata.trainees.filter(function (x) { return x.hasOwnProperty('name'); });

        var dynamic = [];

        dynamic.push = function (id, value) {
            if (!this[id]) {
                this[id] = [];
            }

            this[id].push(value);
        }

        var t = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var minfo = (i, arr[i]['name']);
            dynamic.push(i, minfo);
            //alert(arr[i]['name']);
        }

        var dynamicData = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            dynamicData[i][arr[i]['name']];
        }

        // this is the sample data that i am trying to make it dynamic
        // HERE IS WHERE I AM STUCK
        var d1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
            d1.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

        var d2 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
            d2.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

        var stack = 0,
            bars = true,
            lines = false,
            steps = false;

        function plotWithOptions() {
            $.plot($("#chart_5"),

                [{
                    label: "sales",
                    data: d1,
                    lines: {
                        lineWidth: 1,
                    },
                    shadowSize: 0
                }, {
                    label: "tax",
                    data: d2,
                    lines: {
                        lineWidth: 1,
                    },
                    shadowSize: 0
                }]

                , {
                    series: {
                        stack: stack,
                        lines: {
                            show: lines,
                            fill: true,
                            steps: steps,
                            lineWidth: 0, // in pixels
                        },
                        bars: {
                            show: bars,
                            barWidth: 0.5,
                            lineWidth: 0, // in pixels
                            shadowSize: 0,
                            align: 'center'
                        }
                    },
                    grid: {
                        tickColor: "#eee",
                        borderColor: "#eee",
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        $(".stackControls input").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            stack = $(this).val() == "With stacking" ? true : null;
            plotWithOptions();
        });
        $(".graphControls input").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            bars = $(this).val().indexOf("Bars") != -1;
            lines = $(this).val().indexOf("Lines") != -1;
            steps = $(this).val().indexOf("steps") != -1;
            plotWithOptions();
        });

        plotWithOptions();

    });
```

Comment: You're trying to code synchronously using an async function ( `ajax()`). Move the code, that is dependent on the ajax query, inside the success handler and you should be fine.

Comment: i am already getting the data correctly the formatting of the data is what i am facing issues with, i will move them but i need help with the data format.

Comment: your problem is not the dataformat, but when accessing `xdata` before the ajax call has finished. Hence it is `null` and you should receive an error. There is a reason `ajax()` does not return the result, but requires you to specify callbacks on one way or the other.

Comment: @Sirko i have tried it now after i have moved it in the data is arrived correctly but i am having issues with the formatting of the data in the correct way in order to make the flot graph work, please help me

Comment: First error when debugging your code is this line `dynamicData[i][arr[i]['name']];`.  This is doing nothing - what should it do?

Comment: What value are you trying to plot?  What's the x axis, what's the y axis?  `name` on x, and `percent` on y?